# Website not opening without www but opens with it

Tags: django, apache, deployment

I am trying to deploy my website. It works fine with www but I get apache default page when I enter the website without www.
I don't understand where the problem comes from, I have already set an Alias as you can see here.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t>
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

        ServerName foot-bet.com
        ServerAlias www.foot-bet.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =foot-bet.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Can you please help me ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I try to acess without www just "foot-bet.com" and works fine, so I guess you figure it out.